# Why kiss the Kotel?

Tags: sources-mekorot, kotel-western-wall, kissing, shechinah

Is there any particular reason for kissing the Western Wall and are there any traditional sources that mention kissing the wall?

I ask because someone I know said that the reason for kissing the wall is because the Shechinah rests in the wall. However, I thought the Shechinah rests in the Holy of Holies (though I could be mistaken).

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12092/kissing-the-land-of-israel

Comment: The Shechina rests in many places. It is most present in Holy of Holies, but not to the total exclusion of others.

Answer (score -1):

Rav Acha said: The Shechinah has never departed from the Western Wall. [Shemot Rabbah 2:2]

The Shechinah rests upon the Western Wall. [Zohar, Mishpatim 116]

Why would kissing it not be allowed?

Comment: He asked about the western retaining wall of the Herodian expansion of the Temple mount, not the western wall of the Temple.

Comment: @DoubleAA that is what is referred to as the *Western Wall* since that is what was left after the second temple was destroyed.

Comment: @sabba The western wall of the Temple was indeed not destroyed as it says explicitly in all these Midrashim and the other three walls were indeed destroyed. All 4 of the retaining walls were not destroyed obviously otherwise the mountain-complex would collapse. This is all explicit in the midrash

Comment: What is the significance of the Shechina vis-a-vis kissing. Do you kiss the members of your minyan because ומנין לעשרה שמתפללין שהשכינה עמהם?

Comment: @Alex -- You could.  It's a matter of custom.  You are not obligated.